# Wordpress / Prevent Server from Caching CSV Files

Tags: wordpress, caching, server

I am creating a CSV File with PHP and save it to the Server.

The Server Cache is enabled, but this makes the CSV File being cached too.

I am looking for a way to prevent that. Without Plugins...

What I tried: adding code to htaccess (which also prevents the browser from caching the file, please don#t focus on answers related to htaccess and browser-caching, thanks!).
And I also tried to add some header() Code .. but I am not sure where.

I added this when I create the File:

```
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment filename="sample.csv"');
    header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

But it's not working when I open the file - it gets cached. But I guess this is the false spot for adding this code. But where else?
I also tried to add an action to 'init' and ask if the called file is the file I don't want to be cached, but of course, functions.php is not called when opening a file from the server.

Does someone have an Idea?

Comment: Change the name of the file every time it changes? (eg. `sample-20190718.csv`)

Comment: I can't do that, because a Platform gets the file every day, and it's not possible for them to get files with a different name every day.

Answer (score 2):

Put this code in .htaccess file , it may help you . prior puting this make sure you have done backup of your website.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(pdf|csv|doc)$">
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive Off
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        FileETag None
        Header unset ETag
        Header unset Pragma
        Header unset Cache-Control
        Header unset Last-Modified
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Expires "Mon, 10 Apr 1972 00:00:00 GMT"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: As I said, this is only for the browser cache. But I am looking for a solution to disable the server cache for a specific url or file!